# Iframe youtube multiple videos tracking

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have a webpage with several iframe youtube videos embedded in it.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video2"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/video3"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In the script side, i have to find which video is clicked and started to play.

> example: if a user click video1, then the script alert
>   "http://www.youtube.com/embed/video1"
>
> if a user click video2, then the script alert
>   "http://www.youtube.com/embed/video2"
>
> if a user click video3, then the script alert
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/video3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use YouTube IFrame API ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference ) which responds to video state changes.
To each src add `?enablejsapi=1`, setup api and take a look at `onStateChange` event.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/6Lz7uvn3/)

Comment: I have zero knowledge in it..it would be helpful for me, if you give sample simple code..i will make up it for mulitple

Comment: Added link to example :)

Comment: Its really aweseme.Thank you so much.